# Slicing out parts of a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported a xlsx file into R studio and somehow it changed the file a bit and now i have a weird new date in my time column, does anybody know how to extract the dates from 1899 in my time column. I tried it with the dplyr package but it didn't worked. I am thankful for every help

cheers Lorenz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dzlA.jpg)

PS: the screenshot of the data frame is in the link.

It looks like that:

1899-12-31 07:29:16

but it should look like that:

07:29:16

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This questions looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101019/need-to-remove-date-from-timestamp/67101151#67101151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted part of the strings using `sub`, for example like this:

```
df$Time <- sub("^\\S+\\s", "", df$Time)
```

or using backreference:

```
sub("(.*) (.*)", "\\2", df$Time)
```

or, you can pick out the wanted part using `stringr`s function `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$Time, "\\S+$")
```

Comment: I used the stringr function and it worked out perfect. Thank you very much!!